Unexpected behavior with object initializer
Not exactly sure how this is working. Not even sure how I can even use object initializer while building the Child class.  And then how its overriding my default Test class.
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Child child = new Child
        {
            Test = { Name = "hello" }
        };

        //child.Test.Name prints out "hello"
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child()
    {
    }
}

public abstract class Parent
{
    public Test Test { get; }

    protected Parent()
    {
        Test = new Test { Name = "Default" };
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Expected an error can't I shouldn't be able to use object initializer on Test and the default can't be changed.

You are thinking of
Test = new Test { Name = "hello" }

which is indeed not allowed because Test does not have a setter.
On the other hand,
Test = { Name = "hello" }

is totally fine because it doesn't set Test. It just sets Test.Name, and Name indeed has a setter.
From the spec,

A member initializer that specifies an object initializer after the equals sign is a nested object initializer, i.e., an initialization of an embedded object. Instead of assigning a new value to the field or property, the assignments in the nested object initializer are treated as assignments to members of the field or property.


This is akin to:
Child child = new Child();
child.Test.Name = "hello";

Nothing illegal about that.
It is arguably a little unclear when it (the access on Test) is an assignment via set versus a mutate via the get, but one big clue here is the lack of a new; just using = {...} goes via the get.

As others have pointed out - if you were to use new Test { ... }, you would've been actually creating a new instance, which is not allowed here because you cannot assign a new value directly to the Test property since it doesn't have the set accessor; whereas { ... } is just how you specify new values for existing properties in an existing instance that has been already created and instantiated. You're not creating a new instance  - that's what the new keyword is for.
You can take a closer inspection via SharpLab:
This:
Child child = new Child
{
    Test = { Name = "hello" }
};

becomes the following at lower level C# (IL code):
Child child = new Child();
child.Test.Name = "hello";
Child child2 = child;

As you can see, you already initialize the Test property via the constructor of the Parent class. Only then, you simply assign a new value to the Name property of an existing instance - you're not changing the Test property itself.
If the derived class has a constructor and the base class also has a constructor, the derived class will invoke the constructor of the base class. It's exactly the same as:
public class Foo
{
    public bool Bar { get; set; }

    protected Foo()
    {
        Bar = true;
    }
}

public sealed class Baz : Foo
{
    public Baz() : base() // <-- Notice 'base()' - it's completely optional
    {
    }
}

You can also notice how the constructor of the base class is invoked first:
public class Foo
{
    protected Foo()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message {i} from Foo constructor");
        }
    }
}

public sealed class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar() // : base() is completely optional here
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message {i} from Bar constructor");
        }
    }
}

// ...
var bar = new Bar();

Result:
Message 0 from Foo constructor
Message 1 from Foo constructor
Message 2 from Foo constructor
Message 3 from Foo constructor
Message 4 from Foo constructor
Message 0 from Bar constructor
Message 1 from Bar constructor
Message 2 from Bar constructor
Message 3 from Bar constructor
Message 4 from Bar constructor

Hence the Parent class initializes the Test property.

protected Parent()
{
    Test = new Test { Name = "Default" };
}

this assigns the Test property its one and only value when Parent is created. After this point, Test is set in stone—you can’t assign a new Test object to it.
But because Test itself has a Name property that’s still a regular get; set;, you can change Name to whatever you want. If you want Name to be untouchable too, you’d have to remove the setter in Test.

The surprising part is this syntax:
Child child = new Child
{
    Test = { Name = "hello" }
}

It's NOT trying to assign a new Test object (which would fail since it's get-only). Instead, it's modifying the EXISTING Test object that was created in the Parent constructor.
The sequence:

new Child() runs
Parent() constructor creates Test with "Default"
Object initializer modifies the existing Test.Name

To prevent this, make Name read-only:
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

It's similar to how collection initializers work:
public List<int> Numbers { get; } = new();
var obj = new MyClass 
{
    Numbers = { 1, 2, 3 }  // Adds to existing list
};

Hope this helps! 
